# I want to remove duplicates from the list using for loop.I am getting index out of bound error here:if lst[i]==lst[j]:

Tags: python, duplicates

I have declared a list and sorted it.While iterating the second for loop I am getting :index out
of range error.

lst=[]

```
for i in range(5):
    a=int(input())
    lst.append(a)

lst.sort()
print(lst)

for i in range(0,len(lst)):
    j=i+1
    for j in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i]==lst[j]:
            print("hii")
            lst.pop(j)

print(lst)
```

Comment: Don't change the length of a list while iterating over it...

Answer (score 0):

As you remove elements from `lst` it's length change so your iteration breaks when it tries to access an empty index: **"Index out of bound"**

If you want to keep your structure you could catch that and exit the loop using a try/catch on IndexError but it's really ugly.

A more pythonic solution is to simply cast your list as a set then back to list. This works because sets remove all of their duplicate elements:

```py
>>> list(set([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4,]))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change the length of your list while iterating over it, I am assuming you want to delete all duplicates in your original list. You can use cast the list to a set with

```
set(lst)
```

before you sort or after you sort.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error thrown as you are changing the length of a `list` whist iterating over it.

A simpler approach to removing all duplicates from a `list` would be to create a `set` based on the `list` which is then converted back to a `list` - this should be done before you sort your `list` as a `set` (by definition) does not preserve ordering of elements.

Using your example:

```py
lst = []

for i in range(5):
    a=int(input())
    lst.append(a)

lst = list(set(lst)) # Remove duplicates from list
lst.sort() # Sort list
```